# OPENFILENAME open dialog

Tags: c++, file, winapi

i want to get a full file path by open file dialog in win32.
 i do it by this function:

```
  string openfilename(char *filter = "Mission Files (*.mmf)\0*.mmf", HWND owner = NULL)      {
  OPENFILENAME ofn  ;
  char fileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
  ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
  ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
  ofn.hwndOwner = owner;
  ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
  ofn.lpstrFile = fileName;
  ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
  ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
  ofn.lpstrDefExt = "";
  ofn.lpstrInitialDir ="Missions\\";

  string fileNameStr;
  if ( GetOpenFileName(&ofn) )
    fileNameStr = fileName;

  return fileNameStr;
}
```

it's work fine and return path . but i can't write into the that file i get path of it with openfilename.

note :
 i call this code to write  to the file (serialization):

```
string Mission_Name =openfilename();
ofstream  ofs ;
ofs =  ofstream ((char*)Mission_Name.c_str(), ios::binary   );
ofs.write((char *)&Current_Doc, sizeof(Current_Doc));
ofs.close();
```

Comment: did you checked value of `fileNameStr` ?

Comment: That `LPCSTR` cast gives me the creeps... What is the declaration of `MyfilePath`?

Comment: i think (not sure)this will be the problem with a `\0` in your string casting.

Comment: Zigma i checked value and it's true & contain full file path.

Comment: Lots of issues.  Don't try to write to files in c:\program files.  Don't write binary data to a .txt file.  Don't ignore the requirement for error checking.

Comment: the file is in my d: drive and format is mmf binary! address of file is true i checked but why can't write into file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this for write:**

```
string s = openfilename();

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(s.c_str(),       // name of the write
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,          // Creates a new file, always
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL);                  // no attr. template
DWORD writes;
bool writeok = WriteFile(hFile, &Current_Doc, sizeof(Current_Doc), &writes, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

---

**... and read:**

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(s.c_str(),       // name of the write
                   GENERIC_READ,           // open for reading
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   OPEN_EXISTING,          // Creates a new file, always
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL);                  // no attr. template
DWORD readed;
bool readok = ReadFile(hFile, &Current_Doc, sizeof(Current_Doc), &readed, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

---

**Help links:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try closing it and reopen then for writing.