# file writing not working after call to open file dialog

Tags: c++, c, winapi

after call to following function i cant write to any files i tried c++ fstream and c's fopen what's wrong please help thanks in advance
i am using codeblocks mingw windows 7

```
string openFileDialog(HWND hwnd,char *fileFilter,char *defaultExtension)
{
    string fileName = "";
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char szFileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = fileFilter;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = defaultExtension;

    if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) {
        fileName.assign(szFileName);
    }

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the string you return is valid? What happens when `GetOpenFileName` returns `FALSE`? *How* do you open the file? And why do you call `ZeroMemory` before returning? It's not needed as the structure is not used any more.

Comment: What is `fileFilter`'s value? It's a tricky one. And also, why is it not a `const` parameter?

Comment: i pass openFileDialog(NULL,"Image Files\0*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp\0","*.*"); and filename returned by function is valid,function works as expected but after calling it no further file writing/modifying operation work

Comment: Then there's no error in this function, but how you do the file handling. Please show us how you open and read/write the files.

Comment: any file writing/modifying code is not working after call to openfile dialog function for example i am  adding this code after calling openfiledialog   FILE *w = fopen("a.txt","a");
        fprintf(w,"asdasd");
        fclose(w);

Comment: If you change folder in the dialog it will change the current folder for your process - try adding the `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag.

Comment: If e.g. `fopen` fails, you should check [`errno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use e.g. [`strerror`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc53h9bh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get a printable text of the error.

Comment: @miko1: That is the pitfall of working with relative paths and why you should NEVER do it. ALWAYS use absolute paths.

Comment: @miko1 it may work for now by pure luck, but your filter is one \0 short: It needs to end with two empty strings, not one. This means three consecutive \0 characters, counting the implicit one at the end of the string; your current code only has two. Therefore, you should pass `"Image Files\0*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp\0\0"` instead.

Comment: thanks guys and Jonathan Potter your magical answer worked awesomely OFN_NOCHANGEDIR,i still wonder if it changed the current dir path then why the reading operations was working. thanks Medinoc,Remy,Joachim ;) + how can i accept Potter's answer as right answer ??

Comment: Glad it worked, I'll post it as an answer if you'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change folder in the dialog it will change the current folder for your process - try adding the `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try CreateFile and WriteFile.

```
string s = "file.dat";

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(s.c_str(),       // name of the write
                   GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                   0,                      // do not share
                   NULL,                   // default security
                   CREATE_ALWAYS,          // Creates a new file, always
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                   NULL);                  // no attr. template
DWORD writesBytes;
bool writeok = WriteFile(hFile, &Current_Doc, sizeof(Current_Doc), &writesBytes, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Similar problem, and my answer is here:

[OPENFILENAME open dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791953/openfilename-open-dialog/16792858#16792858)

Comment: @marbel82 it solves problem by not changing process's current working dir.

Comment: @bartimar i've already created my file handling class in c++ so win32's file handling wasn't a option + i lake reputation to make your answer useful :p